# What stat test to use and help with code in R (for a beginner)?

Tags: multiple-regression, manova

i am just wandering what test to use for the following trial:
I have a one treatment at 9 different rates (untreated, 100g, 200g etc) and I want to see how 4 continuous dependent variables and 2 categorical dependent variables respond.

Should I do a pca first and see what response variable I should focus on? Can you do this for the 9 different treatment rates?

I do not know if it is a one-way manova that I need to preform, or multiple regression? I get confused with the R code when I have to seperate the treatments (DV) into the different rates to be compared to the IV.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What I could understood from your question is:

You have one predictor variable (treatment) with 9 categories and 6 outcome variables (4 continuous and 2 categorical). 
You would need **multivariate regression**.

[You may find some pointers to do it in R here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11127/multivariate-multiple-regression-in-r?rq=1)